# How to find greatest value in a column and display it with a "Greatest Value" Flag and display the rest of the new column value as "Not Greatest"

Tags: mysql

I have a table UnitCheck:

[image]

```
enter code here
```

I want to add a new column which will return me a value Greatest if the CostToRestaff value is the highest and should a return a value Not Greatest for every other value of`enter code here CostToRestaff.

CostToRestaff is a calculated column with the formula: 0 * FullDutyC + 10 * WoundedC + 25 * KilledC;

```
enter code here
```

edited:

I was trying more on these lines. Any idea where i am going wrong?

```
''''''

if Unit_ID = A then --A is the user parameter for my procedure
Set check1 = 0 * FullDutyC + 10 * WoundedC + 25 * KilledC;
end if;

if Unit_ID = B then --B is the user parameter for my procedure
Set check2 = 0 * FullDutyC + 10 * WoundedC + 25 * KilledC;
end if;

if Unit_ID = C then --C is the user parameter for my procedure
Set check3 = 0 * FullDutyC + 10 * WoundedC + 25 * KilledC;
end if;
if check1 > check2 AND check1 > check3 then
set Rejection = /*  this is where i need the final answer which should be 
the value itself for eg: 125 - since it is the highest value*/ where Unit_ID = 
A;
elseif check2 > check3 AND check2 > check1 then
Set Rejection = /* this is where i need the final answer in this case since it is not the highest value then it should jump to the else condition*/ where 
Unit_ID = B;
elseif check3 > check1 AND check3 > check2 then
Set Rejection = /* this is where i need the final answer in this case since it is not the highest value then it should jump to the else condition*/ where Unit_ID = 
C;
else set Rejection = "Not Greatest"
end if;

''''''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select
    t.*,
    (rank() over(order by CostToRestaff desc) = 1) isGreatest
from mytable t
```

This gives you a `0/1` flag that indicates if the current is has the greatest value of `CostToRestaff` across the whole table - which I find more meaningful that string `'(Not) Greatest'`. If there are top ties, they would all get the `1` flag.

If you want that as a string value:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when rank() over(order by CostToRestaff desc) = 1
        then 'Greatest'
        else 'Not Greatest'
    end isGreatest
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, you can use a subquery or a join to compute the maximum value:

```
select
    t.*,
    (select max(CostToRestaff) from mytable) =  CostToRestaff isGreatest
from mytable t
```